# When we use both "present perfect" and "past" in a sentence

Tags: tense

> I remember that I met a girl in a club and she was more beautiful than **any of the girls that I've ever met.** And her name is Jina.

Here, ***any of the girls that I've ever met*** can refer to both the girls that I'd met before I met Jina in the club and the girls that I met after I'd met Jina in the club, because present perfect refer to a unspecific time, which could be before or after an specific event. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that "present perfect refers to a unspecific time". But what you say is not enough to explain the use of present perfect in your sentence.

Your example fits into this one:

We use present perfect when we are talking about our experience up to the present:

Note: We often use the adverb ever to talk about experience up to the present:

My last birthday was the worst day I have ever had.

Note: and we use never for the negative form:

Have you ever met George? Yes, but I’ve never met his wife. -

To be more clear about your sentence, "any of the girls that I've ever met" refers to the girls that I'd met **before** I met Jina in the club.